# How do I create instance variables from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 3.2. Here's my code:

```
transports = %w(car bike)

transports.each do |transport|
  @transport = transport.classify.all
end
```

That code is not working, but I want the results to be:

```
@cars = Car.all
@bikes = Bike.all
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
transports.each do |transport|
  instance_variable_set("@#{transport}", 
                        transport.classify.constantize.all)
end
```

**Update** Given that the entries in the `transports` array are now singular the correct code to get the result you want is

```
transports.each do |transport|
  instance_variable_set("@#{transport.pluralize}", 
                        transport.classify.constantize.all)
end
```

Comment: If you change `transport.classify.all` to `transport.classify.constantize.all`, your answer will be correct. `classify` does not get the class constant. Also, you will not need to pluralize the `transport` string, since it is already in plural form.

Comment: Many many thanks. Can I post a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555660