# How to iterate instance variables within instance variables in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 3.2. I have the following code:

```
# transports_controller.rb
@transports = %w(car bike)

@transports.each do |transport|
  instance_variable_set("@#{transport.pluralize}", 
                        transport.classify.constantize.all)
end

# transports/index.html.erb
<% @transports.each do |transport| %>
  <h1><%= transport.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
  <% @transport.pluralize.each do |transport_item| %>
    <%= transport_item.name %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The controller code is correct, but the view code is wrong. `@transport.pluralize.each` cannot be called literally . Expected result is:

```
<h1>Cars</h1>
Ferrari<br>
Ford<br>

<h1>Bikes</h1>
Kawasaki<br>
Ducati<br>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I get that you are not getting your expected result, but what *are* you getting? An error? Output is in the wrong order? Which call to `@transport.pluralize` is failing? Need a little more to go on here.

Comment: The `@transport.pluralize` cannot be called literally. I haven't tested this, but I'm sure that is not the way to write it.

Comment: Are you talking about in the loop? If so, just like you do `instance_variable_set`, there is an `instance_variable_get`. Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Great great. That's what I wanted. Thanks for the tip. You can put that as an answer, then I will tick it, so that you get points. Thanks again.

Comment: glad that's what you were looking for. Submitted as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you use `instance_variable_set`, there is an [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) available.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create instance variables for this, just use an array (or a hash):

```
transport_classes = [Car, Bike]

@transports = transport_classes.map { |transport_class|
  [transport_class, transport_class.all]
}
# this returns a nested array:
# [
#   [Car, [#<Car id:1>, #<Car id:2>]],
#   [Bike, [#<Bike id:1>, #<Bike id:2>]
# ]
```

In your view:

```
<% @transports.each do |transport_class, transport_items| %>
  <h1><%= transport_class.to_s.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
  <% transport_items.each do |transport_item| %>
    <%= transport_item.name %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```